# sql query is printed in execution

Tags: php, mysql

When I execute the following code, the query highlighted in yellow in the attached image gets printed in the page. I don't want to print that sql. What is the wrong in my code segment?

[image]

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["stu_performance_activity_submit"]))
    {
    $stu_performance_main_category = $_REQUEST["stu_performance_main_category"];
    $stu_performance_sub_category = $_REQUEST["stu_performance_sub_category"];
    $stu_performance_activity_name = $_REQUEST["stu_performance_activity_name"];
    $stu_performance_activity_date = $_REQUEST["stu_performance_activity_date"];
    $stu_performance_activity_description = $_REQUEST["stu_performance_activity_description"];

    $newc = "INSERT INTO stu_performance_activity 
                    (stu_performance_activity_id, 
                    stu_performance_main_category, 
                    stu_performance_sub_category, 
                    stu_performance_activity_name, 
                    stu_performance_activity_date, 
                    stu_performance_activity_description) 
            VALUES ('', 
                    '$stu_performance_main_category', 
                    '$stu_performance_sub_category', 
                    '$stu_performance_activity_name', 
                    '$stu_performance_activity_date', 
                    '$stu_performance_activity_description')";

    if($connection->query($newc) === TRUE) 
        {   

        }
    else
        {
        echo "Error: " . $newc . "<br>" . $connection->error;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Print a useful wrror message like `$connection->error`

Comment: Do you start the PHP code with a `<?php` tag

Comment: This solved the issue. I have missed to add <?php Instead, there was on <?. Thanks  @RiggsFolly !

Answer (score -1):

Primary key should be NULL during INSERT. Rewrite your query in a way like

```
$newc = "INSERT INTO stu_performance_activity 
                    (stu_performance_activity_id, 
                    stu_performance_main_category, 
                    stu_performance_sub_category, 
                    stu_performance_activity_name, 
                    stu_performance_activity_date, 
                    stu_performance_activity_description) 
            VALUES (NULL, 
                    '$stu_performance_main_category', 
                    '$stu_performance_sub_category', 
                    '$stu_performance_activity_name', 
                    '$stu_performance_activity_date', 
                    '$stu_performance_activity_description')";
```

Comment: Updated the query with null for PK. But the result is the same

Comment: What db driver do you use? PDO or soemthing else? @SupunDhananjaya

Comment: How can I check that? I use mysql default settings. However, exactly similar queries works in my other pages with same settings.